# Strip string from other string if it starts with it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript, how do I strip a string from other string if the other string starts with the first string?

```
var matcher='Hello';

var s1='hello everyone';
console.log(someFunction(s1,matcher);
//Should return ' everyone', and should be case insensitive

var s2='xhello everyone';
console.log(someFunction(s2,matcher);
//Should return nothing (either NULL or FALSE or "" would be fine) since s2 doesn't start with 'Hello'
```

Demo for the three answers: https://jsfiddle.net/dynvgn1k/

Comment: Search for the first string and replace with `nothing`("").

Comment: @noob  How to force it to start at the beginning?

Comment: Use `^`. It's called anchoring from start. It will look for your match at beginning of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use regex just use:

```
s1.toLowerCase().indexOf(matcher.toLowerCase()) === 0 && s1.substr(matcher.length)
//=>  everyone

matcher='hi'
s1.toLowerCase().indexOf(matcher.toLowerCase()) === 0 && s1.substr(matcher.length)
//=> false
```

Use of `toLowerCase` will make it ignore case comparison. `indexOf` returns position of search string in subject and position `0` means search word is found at start.

Comment: Yes I just added it in answer.

Comment: Ah, so this will just verify that the string starts with the other string.  I expect I would then have to find the length of the second string, and return that many characters from the first string?

Comment: You just want result to be true/false right? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex will do it

```
function someFunction(str,matcher) {
    var regex = new RegExp('^' + matcher, 'i');
    return str.replace(regex, '');
}
```

Comment: Note that this returns the original array if the string doesn't start with the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var matcher='Hello';
var s1='hello everyone';
s=s1.split(" ");
(s[0].toUpperCase() ===matcher.toUpperCase() )?console.log(s[1]):console.log("nothing");
```

Comment: While I showed a `" "`, I didn't wish to depend upon it.